# Status/Data from Servlet to JSP(Ajax)?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have one JSP page (async.jsp) and one Servlet (AjaxController.java). AjaxController is processing all the data coming from async.jsp, it works perfect, I can send data with Ajax from async.jsp and get the Parameter in AjaxController. I calculate some values in AjaxController and I want to put some values back to async.jsp and to do something with them in JSP. Example is, if calculation in Servlet is smaller than 10 then return "NOK" and if greate than 10 return "OK". Than I query in jsp which Status i got and do something according to my Status. How can I put some data back to jsp, I have one additional Funktion in servlet, I get data with doPost method, Hand it over to method work() and from method work I want to pass data to jsp. How can I do it? With setAttribute?

Comment: You use Ajax, so you will not have access to Attributes. You can dimply write something into response and read that in javascript

Comment: I am trying it right now. I set response:
response.getWriter().write("validUser:" + message);
response.flushBuffer(); 
But how do I get it in javascript?

Comment: Show the js code that calls the servlet